# What is the number near Mako's shield/hull indicator

Tags: mass-effect

The question is straight forward. Is there for any use, like repair points or something?

And how do I use it?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**, these are *Omnigel (repair) points*.

You need at least 15 Omnigels to do some repairs.

Repair your Mako with the <kbd>Y</kbd> button on XBox (<kbd>F</kbd> on PC).

Comment: IIRC repairing stops if you move while it's occurring.